# jsrender check if a string is empty ""

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I want to find out whether a string is empty or not i am trying to do

```
 {{if closedOn !=  "" }}
```

but it is not giving me proper output

Comment: what value you are passing to `closedOn` variable?

Comment: Use this `closedOn.toString()` to convert `closedOn` value to string,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{if closedOn}}`

should work - assuming closedOn can be either a Date or a value you want to exclude such as undefined/null/"".

Answer (score 1):

You can make checking like that:

```
if (closedOn) {
     // closedOn is defined and it length > 0
}
```

Your way to check is not properly right, cause

```
(undefined != "") is true
(null != "") is true
```